# listing sd card files on a tft screen

Tags: sd-card, tft

I'm currently working on a **Arduino** project that plays **audio** files from **SD card** through a **speaker**.

First Arduino sends the list of all music files, and when I send it a file name, the music is played.

The project is working well but there's no **GUI**. Everything has to be done via **serial**, and now I want to add a **TFT** screen that will list the music files on the screen, so that whenever I **touch** a file name  it should be played.

I haven't bought the TFT yet, and that's because I have a little question for which I need an answer.

**If I start listing the files, can I scroll up and down ? Because at some point the TFT screen will become full of text, and I don't want the text to be overwritten.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> If I start listing the files, can I scroll up and down ? Because at some point the TFT screen will become full of text, and I don't want the text to be overwritten.

If you program that kind of facility, yes.

A TFT screen is like a blank piece of paper, and you have a set of crayons. You draw on the screen (sometimes with pre-defined shapes, called "letters"). If you want to change what is on the screen you can either throw away your piece or paper and start with a new blank page, or you can get some Tip-Ex® and cover up parts that were there already so you can draw over them.

If you want scrolling you will have to work out for yourself how best to do that given the limited resources you have available.

The simplest method is just to retain a list of the filenames in memory and print just a subset of them on the screen. "Scrolling" then just means displaying a different subset of names.